# problem within my file creator class?

Tags: oop, php

im having small problem within my file creator class .
im a little bit new to OOP so i think i made a fault
here is the class

```
<?php 
class Files{
    public $filename ;
    public $content ;
    function Files($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }
    function createfile()
    {
        $file = fopen($this->filename, "w+") or die('cant create file ');
        return $file ;
    }
    function writetofile($content)
    {
        fwrite($this->createfile,$content) ;
    }
    function closecon()
    {
        fclose($this->createfile);
    }
}
?>
```

and here is how i use it

```
<?php 
include 'classes/class.files.php';
$create = new files('tmp/index.html');
$content = '<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>';
$create->createfile() ;
$create->writetofile($content) ;
$create->closecon() ;
?>
```

when i call test.php file it give me this error

```
Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\AppServ\www\cms\classes\class.files.php on line 16

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\AppServ\www\cms\classes\class.files.php on line 20
```

Comment: It's irrelevant to the question, but you might also want to use the `__construct` function rather than the older format of creating a method with the same name as your class. See [the manual on constructors](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the file pointer resource in a property (instead of calling `createfile` everytime). Also, you're not even calling `createfile` but referencing a non-existent property (for which you should get a notice). Try something like this:

```
class Files{
    public $fp;
    public $filename ;
    public $content ;
    function Files($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }
    function createfile()
    {
        $this->fp = fopen($this->filename, "w+") or die('cant create file ');
    }
    function writetofile($content)
    {
        fwrite($this->fp, $content) ;
    }
    function closecon()
    {
        fclose($this->fp);
    }
}
```

Also, your code is not very PHP5-ready. Your constructor should be called `__construct` (not `Files`) and your methods should have explicit visibility. I also recommend you use the exact case when instanciating your classes:

```
class Files{
    public $fp;
    public $filename ;
    public $content ;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function createfile()
    {
        $this->fp = fopen($this->filename, "w+") or die('cant create file ');
    }

    public function writetofile($content)
    {
        fwrite($this->fp, $content) ;
    }

    public function closecon()
    {
        fclose($this->fp);
    }
}

$create = new Files('tmp/index.html');
```

Comment: what iis the different between using public function __construct($filename) and function Files($filename)

Comment: @Fouad: Files() is PHP4 syntax. It is still working for backward compatibility, but may be deprecated and then removed in future versions of PHP (same goes for visibility and class case).

Answer (score 1):

You should have a private member named `$file`.
`createfile` should not return the file handle; rather, it should set `$this->file` to a valid file handle.
`writetofile` should look like this:

```
function writetofile($content)
{
    $file != NULL || die ('didn\'t create file yet');
    fwrite($this->file, $content);
}
```

Lastly, `closecon` should close the file pointed to by `$this->file`. enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

first, this is a working code snippet:

```
class Files{
    protected $filename ;
    protected $content ;
    protected $fd;

    public function __construct($filename)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }
    public function createFile()
    {
        $this->fd = fopen($this->filename, "w+");
        if ($this->fd === false) {
            throw new Exception('Something bad happened');
        }
    }
    public function writeToFile($content)
    {
        $length = strlen($content);
        if ($length != fwrite($this->fd, $content)) {
            throw new Exception('Something bad happened');
        }
    }
    public function close()
    {
        fclose($this->fd);
    }
}
$create = new Files('index.html');
$create->createFile() ;
$create->writeToFile('blah') ;
$create->close() ;
```

now, the changes:

- your constructor should be called __construct, not Files().
- you missed a property for storing the file handle (in this code,
  named fd)
- the visibility for the methods is missing (by default, they are
  public, but i like to  actually specify it)
- the names for your methods should be lower camel case (like
  createFile)
- dont use die, but throw exceptions
- you didnt check for fwrite  errors
- have the properties private or protected

Comment: *"the names for your methods should be lower camel case (like createFile)"* Mmmm... why is that?

Comment: it's just a convention that make names easier to read. class names are upper camel case and properties and methods lower camel case. some languages enforce it and some don't